# booting to GUI after a move from unity to gnome 3

Tags: 16.04, boot, gnome

my Ubuntu 16.04 was running Unity until I decided recently to move to Gnome 3. Now when I boot I end up in multi user mode and have to login to the console and type starx to start the GUI. I read several posts on the topic, but I am puzzled by my setup:

- I do have `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.dpm=1 radeon.modeset=1 i915.modeset=1"` in `/etc/default/grub`
- I also have env `DEFAULT_RUNLEVEL=2` in `/etc/init/rc-sysinit.conf`
- Executing `systemctl get-default returns graphical.target`

Reading the posts around I am expecting the latter of these 3 config info to be the one exercised on my system, but it does not seem to be the case. Any idea?

post-edit to add the output of `systemctl status display-manager.service`:

```
 ● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager  
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)  
   Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/display-manager.service.d  
            └─xdiagnose.conf  
    Active: active (running) since mar. 2018-03-06 20:11:25 CET; 1 day 19h ago  
   Process: 2141 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited,  status=0/SUCCESS)  
   Process: 2126 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ "$(cat /etc/X11/default-display- manager 2>/dev/null)" = "/usr/sbin/gdm3" ] (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)  
 Main PID: 2151 (gdm3)  
     Tasks: 3  
    Memory: 4.4M  
       CPU: 600ms  
    CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service  
            └─2151 /usr/sbin/gdm3  
 mars 07 17:10:11 port-jct gdm-password][22146]: pam_succeed_if(gdm- password:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "cohen"  
 mars 07 18:44:44 port-jct gdm-password][26575]: pam_succeed_if(gdm-password:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user  "cohen"  
 mars 07 19:39:53 port-jct gdm-password][29033]: pam_succeed_if(gdm-password:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "cohen"  
 mars 07 19:39:53 port-jct gdm-password][29033]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): conversation failed  
 mars 07 19:39:53 port-jct gdm-password][29033]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): auth could not identify password for [cohen]  
 mars 07 19:39:54 port-jct gdm-password][29038]: pam_succeed_if(gdm- password:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user  "cohen"  
 mars 07 21:14:57 port-jct gdm-password][953]: pam_succeed_if(gdm-password:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "cohen"  
 mars 08 07:48:09 port-jct gdm-password][6299]: pam_succeed_if(gdm-password:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "cohen"  
 mars 08 08:50:11 port-jct gdm-password][9472]: pam_succeed_if(gdm-password:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "cohen"  
 mars 08 13:35:07 port-jct gdm-password][19396]: pam_succeed_if(gdm-password:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "cohen"
```

Comment: What did you do to move to GNOME 3? Also, add the output of `systemctl status display-manager.service`

Comment: I used apt-get install gdm3.  The output you are asking is pretty long :

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code on how to format code and command output

Comment: I looked at it..... and used bloc quotes with >. There was better? edit: you meant the two trailing spaces to add a newline perhaps. I added that.

Comment: What's the output of: `sudo systemctl enable gdm`(may be gdm3)?

Comment: it returns `Synchronizing state of gdm.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install...
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable gdm` and same with gdm3 (replace gdm by gdm3 in the output)

Comment: @Johanncohen-tanugi please don't use block quotes for command output. Use code formatting (four spaces before each line, or select the text and press Ctrl-K)